# Stretched Images are not shown proper in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[In this link the images of shirt is not shown proper in IE](http://radhefashion.com/NEW_HTML/)

Comment: @PaulCrovella You should not have edited this as this "question" only has a linked image. :(

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your preview I assume you mean the images at the bottom, it says you've defined the height in HTML as 210px therefore they look stretched because they're being told to be!

I'd suggest defining the width in CSS and setting the height: auto;

This way the images will be controlled and appear as they should do.